# Álbum de Fotos Android

Tags: android, picasso

Eu estou montando um álbum, e com o código abaixo, consigo visualizar todas as imagens:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout , viewGroup, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()));

        return view;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

So que desta forma, a memoria do dispositivo se esgota rápido demais.
Por isso encontrei duas APIs que deveriam fazer o mesmo trabalho: Picasso e Glide.
Mas ao utilizar estas linhas, as imagens não aparecem no ImageView.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout , viewGroup, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        //Nenhuma das duas abaixo funciona
        //Picasso.with(getApplication()).load(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString())).into(image);
        //Glide.with(GaleriaActivity.this).load(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString())).into(image);

        return view;
    }
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é que você está usando `Uri.parse`. Na verdade você deve inserir a URL diretamente como parâmetro do método `.load()` no Glide ou Picasso. Veja abaixo o correto como seria:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load("https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg")
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(ivImgGlide);
```

Então como você está passando uma lista de URLs, presumo eu, você deve fazer desta forma:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(getItem(position).toString())
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(ivImgGlide);
```

Comment: Funcionou, vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: @EversonD.Ferreira vou dar um +1 na sua pergunta, não quero que ela fique negativa. Outras pessoas podem passar pelo mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getItem(position).toString()));
Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(image);
```

---

Uma dica:

Inflar um layout para cada item do adapter pode se tornar custoso e fazer com que o scroll não fique suave. Recomendo a utilização do padrão [ViewHolder](http://blog.alura.com.br/utilizando-o-padrao-viewholder/)